# DropDownList show the whole object instead of object property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-select

I have DropDownList that read fils from my database and show this files in my DropDownList.

The current solution is show on my DropDownListItem System.Web.Mvc.SelectList instead of my Object property. I want to include a drop down list of my object (read from database) across my webpage.

This is my object:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string fileName { get; set; }

    public string browser { get; set; }

    public string protocol { get; set; }

    public string family { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<MyObject> list = db.MyObjects.Where(x => x.family == "Web").ToList();
    ViewBag.Files = lList;
    return View();
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
  @Html.DropDownList("File",new SelectList(ViewBag.Files))
```

What i want to see in my DropDownList is my `protocol`  property.

Comment: change this in controller ViewBag.Files =new SelectList(list,"Id","protocol)";

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<MyObject> list = db.MyObjects.Where(x => x.family == "Web").DistinctBy(x=> x.protocol).ToList();
    ViewBag.Files = new SelectList(list,"Id","protocol");
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Why does not contain a definition for 'DistinctBy' and no extension method 'DistinctBy' ?

Comment: you need to add assembly reference for linq

Comment: I mean that it still not working, i still see only System.Web.Mvc.SelectList instead inside my DropDownList

Comment: what exactly do you want to see in the drop down, give some example.

Comment: replace @Html.DropDownList("File",new SelectList(ViewBag.Files)) with @Html.DropDownList("File",(SelectList)ViewBag.Files)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("File", new SelectList(ViewBag.Files, "id", "fileName"))
```